# Unable to open attachment link in MS Teams

Tags: node.js, angular, azure-blob-storage, microsoft-teams

I have a working extension application through which I am creating tasks in Microsoft Teams Planner, using the API, I am also sending `attachments`.

**Note:** the files are uploaded into `Azure Storage Account` which means the URL of the attachment will be something like `https://mydocs.blob.core.windows.net/container/test.png`

The task is successfully sent to the planner, but when I click the attachment from there it shows me:

[image]

But when I open the link in the new tab or from the `open in new window` option it displays the image with no issues.

---

Do I need to upload the images in `Sharepoint` to be accessible in the MS Teams environment?

If yes then what is the logic behind that and how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding your blob url in attachments manually (Click Add attachment -> Link -> paste blob url) in planner app and see how it works ?

Comment: In that case, it opens the image in the new tab (browser) not in the teams itself.

Comment: Hi, Can you share the request response header your are using when trying to upload using api. Also you can refer below document to get idea on how uploaded files are stored in teams. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/file-storage-in-teams-df5cc0a5-d1bb-414c-8870-46c6eb76686a